# Convert an IFeature to an IElement to display on the graphics layer

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcobjects, c#, .net

I have read some posts and looked at a few different examples but I am still having a problem. My problem seems to lay with the location of the IFeature's shape, they are coming back as x= 590241.41279208846, y= 6284509.0955051426 (looks kind of like a UTM) but in order to see anything in that area they need to be more like x = -12831100.742200622; y = 7674669.7012844728.

This does not seem like a simple mouse point to map point location conversion.

This is my translation code:

```
    public void MoveVisibleContouringLayersToDrawingLayer()
    {
        IElement pElement = null;
        string polylineFeatureLayerBaseName = "Contour lines";
        IGraphicsContainer graphicsContainer = GetGraphicsContainer();
        graphicsContainer.DeleteAllElements();

        IEnumLayer layerEnumerator = MapController.Map.Layers;
        if (layerEnumerator != null)
        {
            try
            {
                ILayer layer = layerEnumerator.Next();
                while (null != layer)
                {
                    if (layer.Name == polylineFeatureLayerBaseName)
                    {
                        IFeatureLayer featureLayer = layer as IFeatureLayer;
                        IGeoFeatureLayer fl = (IGeoFeatureLayer)featureLayer;
                        if (null != featureLayer.FeatureClass)
                        {
                            if (featureLayer.Visible)
                            {
                                IFeatureCursor cursor = featureLayer.Search(null, false);
                                IFeature feature = cursor.NextFeature();
                                while (feature != null)
                                {
                                    // Noticing coordinates are no where near the coordinates I use to get
                                    // shapes to show up in my area. x = -12831100.742200622; y = 7674669.7012844728 
                                    // but the shape I am getting back is x= 590241.41279208846, y= 6284509.0955051426. Could the shape be in UTM?
                                    var a = feature.Shape.GeometryType.ToString();                                                      
                                    var b = feature.Shape.Envelope.UpperLeft.X;
                                    var c = feature.Shape.Envelope.UpperLeft.Y;
                                    var d = feature.Shape.Envelope.LowerRight.X;
                                    var e = feature.Shape.Envelope.LowerRight.Y;

                                    if (feature.Shape.GeometryType ==
                                        ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolyline)
                                    {
                                        if (graphicsContainer != null)
                                        {
                                            IColor color = EsriConversionUtility.ConvertToRgbColor(Colors.Red);
                                            ISimpleLineSymbol simpleLineSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbolClass();
                                            simpleLineSymbol.Color = color;
                                            simpleLineSymbol.Width = 3;

                                            // The IFeature shape it setting the lines geometry. 
                                            IGeometry geometry = feature.Shape;

                                            ILineElement lineElement = new LineElementClass();
                                            lineElement.Symbol = simpleLineSymbol;
                                            IElement elementToAdd = lineElement as IElement;
                                            elementToAdd.Geometry = geometry;
                                            graphicsContainer.AddElement(elementToAdd, 0);
                                        }
                                    }
                                        feature = cursor.NextFeature();
                                }
                            }
                        }                            
                    }

                    layer = layerEnumerator.Next();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(layerEnumerator);
                RefreshView();                    
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm thinking that your data frame is in a different coordinate system to your feature class... Change the line IGeometry geometry = feature.Shape; to IGeometry geometry = feature.Shape**Copy**; *// don't use Shape, bad things can happen* and then add a new line immediately after geometry.Project (ArcMap.Document.FocusMap.SpatialReference); *// to project to the same CRS as the map.* and see if that helps any.

Comment: That did it, thanks Michael. Add as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the problem is that the geometries are in a different coordinate system to the map. Although ArcMap will *project on the fly* that functionality is built in to the renderers (example [IFeatureRenderer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/IFeatureRenderer_Interface/0012000004wn000000/)) and does not apply to geometries as graphics (example [IElement](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//00120000044z000000)). For graphic elements the spatial reference needs to match the map projection the graphic is being added to, most of the time this can be achieved by adding [geometry.Project](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m0000020r000000) to your code; if there is a special transformation required between datums there's a little bit more to it than just calling Project.

```
if (graphicsContainer != null)
{
    IColor color = EsriConversionUtility.ConvertToRgbColor(Colors.Red);
    ISimpleLineSymbol simpleLineSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbolClass();
    simpleLineSymbol.Color = color;
    simpleLineSymbol.Width = 3;

    // The IFeature shape it setting the lines geometry. 
    IGeometry geometry = feature.ShapeCopy; // don't use Shape, it can cause problems
    geometry.Project(ArcMap.Document.FocusMap.SpatialReference); // to project to the same CRS as the map

    ILineElement lineElement = new LineElementClass();
    lineElement.Symbol = simpleLineSymbol;
    IElement elementToAdd = lineElement as IElement;
    elementToAdd.Geometry = geometry;
    graphicsContainer.AddElement(elementToAdd, 0);
}
```

Please note the change to the line that obtains the geometry from the feature, use [ShapeCopy](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/ShapeCopy_Property/002500000331000000/) in almost all situations as this will create a copy of the features' shape which isolates the geometry from the feature, if you get [the shape](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/Shape_Property/002500000330000000/) directly you are playing with the *real* geometry associated with the feature and any modifications you make to the geometry object from then are made to the *shape of the feature* (including being assigned the next features' geometry) which can cause big problems.. read the comments on [IFeature.Shape](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/Shape_Property/002500000330000000/) and [IFeature.ShapeCopy](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/ShapeCopy_Property/002500000331000000/) which instructs the user to use ShapeCopy to get a copy of the geometry if they intend to modify the object in any way.